# Resizing Thumb Template Control on Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've dynamically placed a user control on a `Canvas` as the `VisualTree` root in a `Thumb` control. I can move the thumb control correctly, but can only correctly re-size the control while resizing from the east, southeast, and south rectangles defined in the user control.

```
//Instantiate a new Thumb control to be placed on the canvas.
var myThumb = new Thumb();
myThumb.Name = "myThumb";

//Instantiate a new ThumbTemplate and ElementFactory with my user control.
var myThumbTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Thumb));
myThumbTemplate.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(MyUserControl), "myUserControl");

//Set the thumb template to the newly instantiated template.
myThumb.Template = myThumbTemplate;

//Point the DragDelta and DragCompleted events to local methods.
myThumb.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(myThumb_DragDelta);
myThumb.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(myThumb_DragCompleted);

//Add the thumb to the canvas control.
this.myCanvas.Children.Add(myThumb);
Canvas.SetZIndex(myThumb, 1);
Canvas.SetTop(myThumb, 75);
Canvas.SetLeft(myThumb, 50);
```

In the `DragDelta` method, this approach works to resize the user control from the east resizing rectangle:

```
var myThumb = sender as Thumb;
if (myThumb != null)
{
    var myUserControl = myThumb.Template.FindName("myUserControl", myThumb) as MyUserControl;
    if (myUserControl != null)
    {
        myUserControl.Width = myUserControl.OldWidth + e.HorizontalChange;
    } 
}
```

But wherever I attempt to do that plus set the `Canvas.Top` of the `Thumb` control  (Ie. from the North re-size rectangle), I don't get the results I expected:

```
double top = Canvas.GetTop(finderThumb) + e.VerticalChange;
myUserControl.Height = myUserControl.OldHeight - e.VerticalChange;
Canvas.SetTop(myThumb, top);
```

What happens then is that the control moves up and down in the canvas control but only ever re-sizes by one pixel, regardless of the Vertical or Horizontal Change. Any ideas as to why this happens and suggestions for resolving the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to Use this class (ResizeThumb) which is explained in this example
[WPF Diagram Designer: Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)

```
public class ResizeThumb : Thumb
{
    public ResizeThumb()
    {
        DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(this.ResizeThumb_DragDelta);
    }    

    private void ResizeThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Control item = this.DataContext as Control;
        if (item != null)
        {
            double deltaVertical, deltaHorizontal;

            switch (VerticalAlignment)
            {
                case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                    deltaVertical = Math.Min(-e.VerticalChange, 
                        item.ActualHeight - item.MinHeight);
                    item.Height -= deltaVertical;
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Top:
                    deltaVertical = Math.Min(e.VerticalChange, 
                        item.ActualHeight - item.MinHeight);
                    Canvas.SetTop(item, Canvas.GetTop(item) + deltaVertical);
                    item.Height -= deltaVertical;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            switch (HorizontalAlignment)
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    deltaHorizontal = Math.Min(e.HorizontalChange, 
                        item.ActualWidth - item.MinWidth);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(item, Canvas.GetLeft(item) + deltaHorizontal);
                    item.Width -= deltaHorizontal;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    deltaHorizontal = Math.Min(-e.HorizontalChange, 
                        item.ActualWidth - item.MinWidth);
                    item.Width -= deltaHorizontal;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example grabbed from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.dragdelta.aspx) shows it adding e.VerticalChange instead of subtracting. Maybe that is the issue?

```
void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    //Move the Thumb to the mouse position during the drag operation
    double yadjust = myCanvasStretch.Height + e.VerticalChange;
    double xadjust = myCanvasStretch.Width + e.HorizontalChange;
    if ((xadjust >= 0) && (yadjust >= 0))
    {
        myCanvasStretch.Width = xadjust;
        myCanvasStretch.Height = yadjust;
        Canvas.SetLeft(myThumb, Canvas.GetLeft(myThumb) +
                                e.HorizontalChange);
        Canvas.SetTop(myThumb, Canvas.GetTop(myThumb) +
                                e.VerticalChange);
        changes.Text = "Size: " +
                        myCanvasStretch.Width.ToString() +
                         ", " +
                        myCanvasStretch.Height.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, when I don't attempt to set the top of the control, I seem to be getting the correct behavior by subtracting the VerticalChange in this case. Which is, selecting the top (North) border of the control and dragging up causes the control to increase in height, while dragging down causes the control to decrease in height. The problem then is that the control's N border doesn't stay with the mouse.

Still, even just switching the sign doesn't resolve the issue, which is that the control only re-sizes by one pixel despite the value in VerticalChange.